# What is a "routing decision" in the context of iptables?

Tags: iptables

The [wikipedia article on iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) mentions this

> `PREROUTING`: Packets will enter this chain before a routing decision is made.

Iptables can perform alot of actions on a packet, e.g. `DROP` it `JUMP` it to another chain for further processing, `DNAT` it to an different destination than was intended etc.
So, of all the actions `iptables` can take, what would *"a routing decision"* encompass?
E.g. does "a routing decision"  encompass every possible action iptables could make? i.e. could you substitute the phrase "a routing decision" with the phrase "a final decision"? i.e.:

> `PREROUTING`: Packets will enter this chain before a *final* decision is made.
>   and this table will - itself - not provide a conclusive decision about how the packets should be handled just make some adjustments to the packet

And would `DROP` count as a routing decision?

Or does "a routing decision" only a apply to the actual action of routing? e.g. forwarding the packet to a new network?

Answer (score 0):

So just to simplify, let's ignore bridging altogether and remain solely in the context of the network layer.

In this context, the 'routing decision' you mention occurs immediately after traversing the `nat` table's `PREROUTING` chain, and it simply means deciding if the packet in question is bound for the local host itself, or should be forwarded on to another host.

These are divergent paths in iptables, thus a decision must be made:

- If the packet is bound for the local host, it leaves the network layer, traversing several `INPUT` chains across several tables before hitting the application layer.
- If the packet is to be forwarded instead, it stays in the network layer and traverses several `FORWARD` chains instead.

The reason this 'decision' is made *after* traversing the `nat` table's `PREROUTING` chain is because that chain is where the destination address would be changed, if you were performing Network Address Translation on those packets.

Targets that affect your traversal of chains and/or tables (i.e. `ACCEPT` and `DROP`) are targets you can jump to by defining those jumps in rules; they are not actions that iptables will take on its own.

It's also worth noting that the chains containing any `ACCEPT` or `DROP` statements would be traversed *after* this 'routing decision' was made, thus have no direct influence on said decision.

There are other places where 'routing decisions' are made, and depending on the context of the packet (bound for local host, leaving local host, etc.), that decision may consist of something different. [This](https://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/c951.html) is a good resource to understand the differences; you can see the 'decision' you mentioned was Step 5 of Table 6-3.